# Как корректно задать размер таблицы?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap4

Есть вот такая табличка:

```
  <table class="table table-dark table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr class="d-flex">
        <th class="col-4" scope="col">f1</th>
        <th class="col-3" scope="col">f2</th>
        <th class="col-2" scope="col">f3</th>
        <th class="col-md-3" scope="col"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let data of datas">
        <tr class="d-flex">
          <td class="col-4">
            data1
          </td>
          <td class="col-3">
            data2
          </td>
          <td class="col-2">
            data3
          </td>
          <td class="col-3">
            <div class="btn-toolbar mb-3">
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-1" >1</button>
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-1" ">2</button>
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-1">3</button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

В которую подгружаются данные при переходе по страницам.

Проблема в том, что на последней странице может быть меньше элементов, чем на всех остальных и как следствие, весь контент под таблицей резко смещается вверх.

Я конечно могу задать размер в пикселях и это скорее всего решит проблему, но , вроде, так не рекомендуют делать.

Comment: число "нехватающих" строк * высота строки => padding-bottom?

Comment: @TotalPusher вы предлагаете через скрипт добавить необходимые отступы?

Comment: @iluxa1810 судя по всему да через js, вы же всё равно подгружаете список на js. Либо задать min-height, не вижу в этом никаких проблем.

Comment: а чем плохо, когда контент смещается вверх? имхо, куча пустого места между таблицей и контентом гораздо хуже.